# angularjs - can't pre select check boxes in checklist model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `checklist-model` for lisitng checkboxes with `ng-repeat`.So I'get all the checked values in the controller as an array. The problem is when the page is refreshed, previously saved data will be populated and some of the checkboxes will be checked on page load. But if I again save the data, the pre populated check boxes will not be returned.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in innerSet track by $index">
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="quest in option">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="selected[qn.id][an.ac_id]" checklist-value="quest.id" ng-checked="an.questions.indexOf(quest.id) > -1" > {{quest.quest_text}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using ng-checked to pre select the check boxes.

Comment: @tymeJV indexOf is the condition for ng-checked and its working fine

Comment: My bad... thought it wasn't for some reason :\

Comment: are you reassigning the array to be filled with the newly selected checkboxes? or are you pushing the newly selected to the old array? in other words: do you replace the array or do you add the new values to the old array?

Comment: @Guinn reassigning is happening

Comment: @I'mnidhin So can't you change the bit of code that reassigns the array with arr.push()? You can check if the array is undefined for a first-visit, if so then initialize the array and add the values, then after refresh if the array isn't undefined go with arr.push(), or am I thinking too simple now..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to convert my comment to an answer, instead of reassigning the array from scratch after a  refresh, do a check whether the array is currently empty. If so, fill it with data, if not, add data with array.push().